# Foreign exchange in Cuba - how to prepare with cash?

Tags: money, exchange, mexico, cuba

I am Australian travelling to Mexico, Cuba and Costa Rica. What is the best way to prepare for having currency in Cuba especially, I believe there is a lack of ATM's and card facilities once you arrive. People have suggested taking GBP but not USD's due to an exchange tax. Would they exchange AUD into Cuban Peso?

Comment: Did you check it? https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g147270-c109329/Cuba:Caribbean:Money.Exchange.html

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88372/cuban-currency-exchange-atm-vs-exchange-office/88846#88846

Answer (score 2):

I sure here has all info that you need.

> With a somewhat weird two currency monetary system and a very unique
>   political/social situation Cuba's foreign currency exchange can appear
>   a bit daunting for a first time visitor, but with some basic info most
>   people should be able to grasp the essentials without too much
>   trouble.
>
> Here are a few thoughts...
>
> ==============================
>
> Cuba is like most other foreign destinations, you bring a major
>   foreign currency and exchange it into the local currency to make
>   purchases while you’re there. Cuban currency is NOT traded
>   internationally, so you can’t buy it in advance. You buy it when you
>   arrive in Cuba.
>
> 1.) The major legal currency for Cuba is the Cuban Convertible Peso, CUC. It’s what you exchange your foreign currency for and make all
>   your purchases with in Cuba. Most tourists will only ever deal with
>   CUC. For international exchange purposes 1.00 Cuban Convertible Peso =
>   $1.00 USD.   Note that there is a 10% penalty charged when exchanging
>   USA dollars cash, so, you will only receive 87 centavos CUC for one
>   USA dollar when changing the money, allowing for the 10% penalty and a
>   3% currency exchange fee. This is discussed further below.
>
> 2.) The second legal currency in Cuba is the simple and lowly Cuban Peso, CUP, which is rarely used by the vast majority of tourists, but
>   it’s still something you should know about as it is perfectly legal
>   for tourists to use it. For example, you can pay the ride in old
>   taxies anywhere in Cuba in CUP. They cost berween 10 CUP and 20 CUP
>   per person depending on the distance and destination. However, you can
>   pay for the service in CUC as well. Just be aware that there is no way
>   to pay 10 CUP in CUC, so that will cost you 50 centavos CUC, which is
>   12 CUPs. You can also use CUP in local shops where Cubans buy their
>   provisions.  Outside of a resort or hotel when you're travelling
>   independently it’s always handy to have a few Cuban Pesos on you. You
>   get about 24 of them for 1 Convertible Peso.
>
> Street food like sandwiches and pizza, fresh fruit drinks and other
>   small purchases are all incredibly cheap. Once you get a feel for Cuba
>   – if you speak a little Spanish it will be even better – there are
>   peso bars and restaurants that can be quite interesting. Movies are
>   cheap too.
>
> Both types of Pesos, CUC and CUP, are legal tender in Cuba and both
>   are completely available to anyone – including foreigners – with no
>   restrictions whatsoever . You can exchange your CUC for CUP at any
>   bank and most non-resort and non-airport Cadecas.  As a first-time
>   visitor to Cuba though or as a resort tourist venturing off the resort
>   for the day you can easily handle ALL your transactions with
>   Convertible Pesos, CUC.  Lastly, if you leave a tip, leave it in CUC.
>
> ==============================
>
> It's not uncommon in certain situations to be scammed by being charged
>   in CUC but given your change in CUP. Therefore it's a good idea to
>   know how to recognize the two different currencies:
>
> Convertible Pesos, CUC: http://www.cubacurrency.com Cuban Pesos, CUP:
>   http://www.cubacurrency.com Note: The 3 CUP bill with the image of Che
>   makes a nice inexpensive souvenir.
>
> =============================
>
> Accurate Exchange Rates: All the internet currency exchange sites
>   (like coinmill.com, xe.com, oanda.com, x-rates.com, etc.) are useless
>   for real budgeting because they only give mid-market rates, ignoring
>   the buy/sell costs that you'll be charged at the bank or Cadeca in
>   Cuba.
>
> At present here is the ONLY website that gives you the exact exchange
>   rates that you will receive at the Bank in Cuba. 
>   http://www.bc.gob.cu/Espanol/tipo_cam...  It's in Spanish, but it's
>   very easy to decipher. Here's how it works...
>
> 1.) The first column, "Compra" (Purchase) is the rate they're charging you to BUY Cuban Convertible Pesos, CUC.
>
> 2.) The second column, "Venta" (Sell) is the rate they're charging you to SELL Cuban Convertible Pesos, CUC.  UK and European travellers: See
>   the asterisk (*) beside the GBP and EUR? That means you multiply
>   instead of divide .
>
> USA travellers: Don't forget to subtract an additional 10% for the
>   surcharge that Cuba charges against your USD - it's the only foreign
>   currency that gets hit with this additional fee. This means $100 USD
>   always equals 87 CUC.
>
> In the past, the Mexican Peso had been considered a poor choice in
>   Cuba, as well, because the exchange rate approximated the 10%
>   surcharge the USD faces.  This has recently been changing, since the
>   spring of 2016.  At times, the exchange rate for Mexican pesos has ben
>   much better, but it has varied a lot.  Since late August of 2016, the
>   rate has stayed fairly consistently good, but there is still a risk
>
> ## that it will revert back to how it was before.
>
> As you can see from the Banco Central de Cuba website mentioned above
>   these foreign currencies are accepted Cuba:  Canadian Dollars CAD
>   Pound Sterling GBP Mexican Pesos MXN Danish Krone DKK Norwegian Krone
>   NOK Swedish Krona SEK Japanese Yen JPY  Euro EUR. Swiss Francs CHF  US
>   Dollars USD (Don't forget the additional 10% surcharge mentioned
>   above.)  Note: Not all banks and Cadecas will handle all these
>   currencies, so to cash your Krone, Krona, etc. you sometimes may have
>   to go to a main branch.
>
> ==============================
>
> Where to exchange your foreign currency:
>
> 1.) The best exchange rate is at any bank.
>
> 2.) The next best exchange rate is at any Cadeca. A Cadeca (Casa de Cambio which means House of Exchange) is a government exchange
>   facility. They're located at airports, many resorts and hotels and at
>   locations all over the Island. 
>   3.) The worst rate can potentially be over-the-counter at any hotel or resort because the rate is not regulated by the government.  If you're
>   an independent traveller or a long term visitor and paying everything
>   in CUC then exchanging at a bank is obviously the most sensible
>   option.  With few exceptions CUP is available at most non-resort
>   Cadecas, non-Airport Cadecas and Banks.  =============================
>
> ## Very Important: You require your Passport for ALL currency exchanges.
>
> Accepted Currency: Always bring new(ish) bank notes, with no rips,
>   tears or markings. Large denominations like $50 & $100 Canadian bills
>   are not a problem, nor are the new Canadian polymer bills an issue. 
>   All foreign coins are useless, same as almost anywhere else in the
>   world. Resort workers or any Cuban in contact with foreigners will
>   accept them, but then you're burdening another tourist with the task
>   of exchanging the coins back into paper cash. In other words,
>   Canadians, leave those Loonies and Toonies at home!
>
> ==============================
>
> ## 1 Tourist Scam in Cuba: Unfortunately it's money exchange. Fortunately though it's also 100% easily avoidable. Always take a
>
> calculator with you so you know the correct amount of CUC that should
>   be coming to you. If you don’t have a calculator do NOT accept any
>   transaction that doesn't come with a printed receipt. Take your time
>   and re-count your money in front of the teller. Do not feel rushed!
>
> =============================
>
> Getting rid of your Cuban Convertible Pesos: You can exchange your
>   leftover CUC at the airport when you leave, but naturally you'll lose
>   money in the exchange. A much better way to handle your CUC is to
>   budget wisely during the last few days of your trip so you don’t
>   arrive at the airport loaded with useless CUC. Bring enough to buy a
>   snack and whatever you wish at Duty Free or save it for your next
>   trip. (Remember though, technically you aren't supposed to take CUC
>   and CUP out of Cuba.)
>
> =============================  Lastly... 
>   1.) Travellers Cheques: They are more hassle than they're worth. They're sometimes difficult to exchange and when you do find a place
>   to accept them you pay a commission to cash them. If they do get lost
>   or stolen they can't be replaced until you return home.
>
> American Express Travellers are accepted at BFI (Banco Financiero
>   Internacional) and BM (Banco Metropoliano) and many Cadecas but are
>   too subject to usual 10% fee. If you do bring them as emergency
>   back-up remember you must have all the original purchase receipts with
>   you.
>
> US tourists should investigate any cost advantage to exchanging their
>   USDs into another foreign currency in order to help lessen the 10%
>   surcharge that Cuba levies against US cash. USD to CAD to CUC is
>   sometimes a little cheaper than exchanging USD directly to CUC. Do the
>   math!
>
> 2.) Canadian Credit Cards: Any of the "Big Five" Canadian banks are fine. Royal Bank, TD/Canada Trust, Bank of Montreal, Bank of Nova
>   Scotia and Canadian Imperial Bank of Commerce.  No problems with PC
>   Financial or Canadian Tire Mastercards as well. And for our friends in
>   Quebec the National Bank Mastercard and Desjardins Visa also work too.
>
> Canadian Debit Cards: Canadian Debit Cards were useless in Cuba but
>   this is finally starting to change. The CIBC Advantage Visa Debit Card
>   is now joined by the TD Canada Trust Visa Debit Card and the Visa
>   Desjardins Prepaid Card working in Cuban ATMs (and Banks and Cadecas)
>   because they display the Visa symbol on the card. Until this becomes
>   common though do NOT assume your Debit Card will be of any use there.
>   Any card without a Visa or Mastercard symbol is useless.
>
> 3.) UK/European Credit and Debit Cards:  Many North American and UK/European Global Debit and Credit Cards like Barclays, Lloyds TSB,
>   Nationwide, Bank of Scotland ( not RBS), Post Office, Yorkshire,
>   Tesco, Halifax, etc. are fine.
>
> Of course they have to be non US affiliated and display the Visa or
>   Mastercard symbol. Visa will work in an ATM, Mastercard means a trip
>   inside to deal with a teller.
>
> Lastly, most UK credit cards now charge a foreign transaction fee of
>   2.75% which they disguise in the exchange rate back to Sterling. National's rate is lower and Post Office doesn't have this charge at
>   all. Contact your card supplier to confirm their charges. 
>   4.) Australian Credit and Debit Cards - It has been reported that some Australian credit and debit cards are no longer, as of 15 Jan 2015,
>   accepted in Cuba. Subsequent investigation could not confirm this with
>   a degree of certainty, as some people claimed that their cards did
>   work but did not say which banks issued their cards. Your cards may
>   work fine, provided the issuing bank has no connection with the US,
>   but you must advise your bank before the travel that you are going to
>   Cuba. The exceptions are the credit and debit cards issued by Citi
>   bank and all pre-purchased Visa and Mastercard Travel Cards. These are
>   not working.
>
> 5.) Useless Credit/Debit Cards: Citi Bank, Capital One, Maestro, MBNA, AMX, any Mastercard from a Canadian Credit Union, Diners, Egg,
>   Santander/RBS, Abbey, Abbey National, Alliance & Leicester, etc. are
>   some of the United States affiliated cards that are useless in Cuba.
>
> 6.) Credit Card versus Cash: There is no extra fee in Cuba for using a credit card. Your Credit Card may be subject to a Foreign Transaction
>   Fee at your home Bank, but there are no additional charges in Cuba.
>   Your credit card purchase in Cuba will be converted from CUC to USD
>   then when the transaction is posted to your statement it will be
>   converted to your local currency.

Source: [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g147270-c109329/Cuba:Caribbean:Money.Exchange.html)